# How to use icon on html

Tags: html, css, unicode, icons, styles

I have this complete code but is not working for me.

```
<style>

.mdi-airplay::before {
    content: "\F01F";
}

.mdi:before {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 24px/1 "Material Design Icons";
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: inherit;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

</style>


<i class="mdi mdi-airplay"></i>
```

Please, is there anything am getting wrong?

Comment: `U+F01F` belongs to a private use range. Use a nonprivate character e.g. `content: "\2708";`. It gives  `✈`      (U+2708, UTF-8   `\xE2\x9C\x88`  Airplane.

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ. Can you help me with the link to get the comprehensive list

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ. Can you help me with the link to get the comprehensive list

Comment: Do you mean something like https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt or https://emojipedia.org/ ?